# Connecting to .\SQLExpress without connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Our group has an existing application, `app1`, written by someone who has left the company. We want to build a similar application, `app2`, with a similar back end in hopes of consolidating both applications in the future.

I am currently working on trying to understand how app1 works, and I'm stumped on how it specifies connections to the local database when running locally. Typically, one would expect the web.config file to specify what database to connect to via `connectionStrings`, but that is not the case with app1. There are no elements contained within the tag:

```
<connectionStrings>

</connectionStrings>
```

I have verified that the application creates and uses a database located in a local instance of sql server 2008 r2 (`.\SQLExpress`). However, when working on app2 with similar configurations, it creates a .mdf file within the `App_Data` directory. I can not find anything that tells app1 to utilize `.\sqlexpress`. How do I configure app2 to behave similar to app1?

Comment: Well, it's kinda obvious but is there any chance to pass the connection string directly to the `DbContext` constructor? In fact which `EF workflow` are you using. `Code First` ?

Comment: @Leron Code First is being used, yes. There is no connection string being passed to the DbContext constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

It turns out EF changes your web.config based on what is available on your machine. When I created `app2`, I had not installed a local database engine, `.\sqlexpress` at the time. In that case, EF creates puts the following in web.config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
</entityFramework>
```

Some time after creating `app2`, I installed a local database enginge. The web.config file from a new application, `app3`, contained this instead:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<entityFramework>
```

Additionally, `app1` did not have either of these, so it seems that it defaults to the latter behavior.

Looks like my issue was attributed to my machine's configuration at the time of creating the project.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue . I got error like underlying provider unable to open like that . 
At that moment what i done is just right clicked on the local database and modified my connection i.e data source .

**example : you have to show the path of your present .MDF file location .Always better place in app_data .**

From then everything works out cool

Anything i can help you please let me know .

Regards